# Using the show typeclass in an instance

Tags: haskell

So I'm very new to Haskell and I've been trying to figure how to use the show typeclass in an instance to print out `[Stat]` in this:

```
module HaskellGame.Datatypes where ....


   data Stat = Stat {
                     name ::String, 
                     value::Int
                    }

    data Monster = Monster {
                           name :: String,
                           stats :: [Stat]
                         }
```

So far the code I've written is this:

```
   module HaskellGame.Graphics where ...

   {-This displays the Monster on the Map-}
    instance Show Monster where
     show (Monster _ _ ) = "M"
   {-This displays the stats of the monster-}
    instance Show Stat where
     show (Stat name value) = (show(name)) ++ ": " ++ (show(value))
```

and I get this error:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `Stat'
            with actual type `([Char], Integer)'
In the expression: ("Toughness", 1)
In the second argument of `Monster', namely
  `[("Strength", 5), ("Toughness", 1)]'
In the expression:
  Monster
    "Dragon" [("Strength", 5), ("Toughness", 1)] [("Fisticuffs", 1)]
```

I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Each `Stat` must have a `Stat` constructor in front of it: `[Stat ("Strength", 5), Stat ("Toughness", 1), Stat ("Fisticuffs", 1)]` or `map Stat [("Strength", 5), ("Toughness", 1),("Fisticuffs", 1)]`

Answer (score 2):

Presumably instead of `instance Show Stat` you meant `instance Show Monster` (since `Stat` already has a suitable `Show` instance).

Comment: I need to make an instance of the Show typeclass for the
Stat datatype so that individual stats can be printed. I want to know how to get each item in the list of stats and show them as :`"Name of Stat" ++ (show(stat_string)) ++ ": " ++ (show(stat_val))`

Comment: @user5652223 You cannot define a show instance for a type synonym. Either change it to `data Stat = ...` or live with the existing show instances. You can, of course, display the `Stat`s however you like within the show instance for `Monster`: `instance Show Monster where show (Monster n ss) = "Monster " ++ n ++ concat [ "\n" ++ sn ++ ":" ++ show sv | (sn,sv) <- ss ]`

Comment: @user2407038 So I changed `type Stat ` to ` data Stat` , but I get the error :                                                                                                                     `Couldn't match expected type Stat  with actual type ([Char], Integer)
    In the expression: ("Toughness", 1)
    In the second argument of Monster, namely
     [("Strength", 5), ("Toughness", 1)]
    In the expression:
      Monster
        "Dragon" [("Strength", 5), ("Toughness", 1)] [("Fisticuffs", 1)] `